# ASUS Slider Sl101 Driver letter access? rather than MTP in Android 4

Tags: windows, usb-connection-mode

I know that Android 3 and 4 use MTP on Windows to allow access to the storage, I have tried the developer switch and the only connection you get is still MTP.. I really need a drive letter to enable several programs that I want to use with my ASUS slider (this question has a good chance of being needed on many Android 4 systems). is there any app or driver that will allow mass storage / drive letter access to Android 4

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, it's a big problem. Google apparently decided to go MTP only route since it does not require unmounting the storage from the Android side when you connect it to your computer. So:

1. You cannot assign a drive letter to an MTP device. [Here's my answer](https://superuser.com/questions/369959/how-do-i-access-mtp-devices-on-the-command-line-in-windows/377008#377008) on superuser.com explaining why.
2. There is a program named [Alt Mounter](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/alt-mounter-simulates-usb-mass-storage-back-on-ice-cream-sandwich/) that supposely solves this problem, and it requires a special software both on the phone and on your computer (Windows/Mac). It is beta and I never tried it.
3. If your phone is rooted, you can install a [Samba Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.funkyfresh.samba&hl=en) on your phone, and simply map a network location to a drive on your computer. No USB is needed, simply access your phone using a drive letter via Wi-Fi. This is the method I use, and it works fairly well for me.